# How to remove some elements in a list based on a rule?

Tags: list-manipulation

I  want to deal with the following list.

```
mylist = Table[cof[i] exp[i], {i, 1, n}]; (*n is very larege *)
```

`exp[ ]` is a function of `{x1, x2, x3, x4, ...}`  and `cof[]` doesn't depend on the variables  `{x1, x2, x3, x4, ...}`.    `exp[ ]` has a pattern like this, `x_  Exp[_]` (see the following example). I want to deal with this list according to some rule.

That is, if `exp[k1]` can be obtained by `exp[k2]` under some permutation of the variables `{x1, x2, x3, x4, ...}`, then I delete the term `cof[k2] exp[k2]` in `mylist` and change `cof[k1]` to `(cof[k1] + cof[k2])`. It seems I should compare all the `exp[]` terms.  I cannot find a way to that for this problem.  Any help?

Here is a simple example,

```
inputlist = {2 const x1 x2 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 3 x2 x2 + 2 x3 x3 - x1 x2 + x2 + cf1], 
             2 x1 x3 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 2 x2 x2 + 4 x3 x3 - x1 x2  ],
             -x1 x3 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 3 x3 x3 + 2 x2 x2 - x1 x3 + x3 ],
             3 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 3 x2 x2 + 4 x3 x3 ],
             -2 Exp[4 x1 x1 + 2 x2 x2 + 3 x3 x3 ]};
```

The corresponding `exp[]` can be written as,

```
exp[1] = x1 x2 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 3 x2 x2 + 2 x3 x3 - x1 x2 + x2];
exp[2] = x1 x3 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 2 x2 x2 + 4 x3 x3 - x1 x2  ];
exp[3] = x1 x3 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 3 x3 x3 + 2 x2 x2 - x1 x3 + x3 ];
exp[4] = Exp[2 x1 x1 + 3 x2 x2 + 4 x3 x3 ];
exp[5] = Exp[4 x1 x1 + 2 x2 x2 + 3 x3 x3 ];
```

Based on the rule, we notice that

```
exp[1] /. {x1 -> x1, x2 -> x3, x3 -> x2} == exp[3]; 
exp[4] /. {x1 -> x2, x2 -> x3, x3 -> x1} == exp[5];
```

so the output list should be

```
outputlist = {
  (2 const Exp[cf1]-1) x1 x2 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 3 x2 x2 + 2 x3 x3-x1 x2 + x2], 
  2 x1 x3 Exp[2 x1 x1 + 2 x2 x2 + 4 x3 x3 - x1 x2 ],
  Exp[2 x1 x1 + 3 x2 x2 + 4 x3 x3]
}
```

Comment: @m_goldberg  Thanks for editing !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this: "and cof[], not exp[], has a pattern like this, x_ Exp[_]" Isn't exp[...] (not cof[]) that has a form of $(\text{product of } x_i)e^{(...)}$? Also, does the exponential always contain a multivariate polynomial? If yes, of what order?

Comment: It seems that part of the problem is deciding if expressions are equivalent under some permutation of the variables.  How many variables do you have?  If we only consider second order multinomials, this test becomes equivalent to graph isomorphism testing (with edge weights), where the `CoefficientArray` would be the adjacency matrix.  This may be slow for lots of variables.  (I'm just thinking aloud about which part may have an efficient solution)

Comment: I guess how difficult this is going to be depends on the exact form of the elements of the list.  Could you give more information about that please?

Comment: Is it possible to define a function or functions with Orderless attribute for this problem?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for your consideration. Yes, the exponential always contain a multivariate polynomial and we don't know the order. I usually expandall this part.  In my case, there are 12 variables.

Comment: @Szabolcs  In fact, I want to get a general function for dealing this prblem firstly. Maybe we should begin with the simple case.

Comment: @unstable  Yes, I think it is promising to use the Orderless character for this problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs a couple of speed-ups can come from pre-classification of the polynomials. Using $f_i(x)=p_i(x)exp(q_i(x))$ for simplicity, then the order of all the terms in $p_i$ and $q_i$ will allow us to determine if we should even bother comparing two $f_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the key challenge is to identify when two expressions are equivalent with a suitable permutation of variables. In this answer I'll address that part first, with a full solution to the problem afterwards.

**The variable permutation part**

Here is an idea to find the variable permutations using the pattern matcher. The basic concept is to create a pattern from `expr1`, essentially by replacing the variables with `Blank[]`s. That pattern is used to define a temporary function `f` which returns the list of symbols matching the `Blank[]`s. The function `f` is then applied to `expr2`. If `expr2` has the same structure as `expr1`, the pattern will match and `f` will return a list of the symbols in `expr2` which correspond to the variables in `expr1`.

```
varPattern = _Symbol?(! NumericQ[#] &);

variableMapping[expr1_, expr2_] := Module[{f},
  With[{vars = Union@Cases[{expr1}, varPattern, -1]},
   f[_] = {};
   f[expr1 /. (# -> Pattern[#, varPattern] & /@ vars)] := vars;
   f[expr2] /. v : {__} :> Thread[v -> vars]]]
```

The function `variableMapping[expr1,expr2]` returns a rule list that transforms `expr2` to `expr1`. For example:

```
variableMapping[a + 2 b, 2 c + d]
(*  {d -> a, c -> b}  *)
```

Using the examples in the question:

```
variableMapping[exp[1], exp[3]]
(*  {x1 -> x1, x3 -> x2, x2 -> x3}  *)

variableMapping[exp[4], exp[5]]
(*  {x2 -> x1, x3 -> x2, x1 -> x3}  *)
```

If there is no match an empty list is returned:

```
variableMapping[exp[1], exp[2]]
(*  {}  *)
```

**The full answer**

I'll step through this using global variables for easier reading, but of course you would want to put it all into a `Module` eventually.

First we need to separate the `inputlist` into `cof` and `exp` terms. There is probably a much smarter way to do this, but this works:

```
vars = x1 | x2 | x3;
a = inputlist /. {Exp[_] -> 1, vars -> 1}
b = inputlist /. ___ Exp[x_] :> x /. vars -> 0
cof = a Exp[b];
exp = inputlist/cof;
```

Now use the `variableMapping` function on each pair of elements in `exp` to find the list of replacements. For this problem the actual variable permutation is not required, we just need to know if one exists, so the check is simply whether `variableMapping` returns an empty list or not:

```
reps = #2 -> #1 & @@@ 
  Select[Subsets[Range@Length@exp, {2}], 
   variableMapping @@ exp[[#]] != {} &]
(*  {3 -> 1, 5 -> 4}  *)
```

There may be cases where three or more `exp` terms are considered interchangeable, so we need to prune the replacement list:

```
reps = GatherBy[reps, First][[All, 1]];
```

Now all that's required is to modify the `cof` list according to the rules set out in the question:

```
(cof[[#2]] += cof[[#1]]; cof[[#1]] = 0) & @@@ reps;
cof
(*  {-1 + 2 const E^cf1, 2, 0, 1, 0}  *)

outputlist = cof exp

(*  {E^(2 x1^2 + x2 - x1 x2 + 3 x2^2 + 2 x3^2) (-1 + 2 const E^cf1) x1 x2,
     2 E^(2 x1^2 - x1 x2 + 2 x2^2 + 4 x3^2) x1 x3,
     0,
     E^(2 x1^2 + 3 x2^2 + 4 x3^2),
     0}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks, waiting for your complete answer.

Comment: @Orders, see the update.

Comment: Thanks! However, I realized that I should use  a numerial method to deal with this problem. Because the computation is not easy for a large expressions in this case.